# Changing enumeration of divisions to roman numbers

Tags: numbering

Please consider the following **MWE**. By default some lists (list of figures, list of tables) are numbered with arabic numbers in `scrbook` and some not (bibliography, index). How can I make LaTeX to use for these lists roman numbers instead of arabic numbers and arabic numbering only for the divisions `chapter`, `section` etc.

**Example**

I List of figures

II List of tables

1.Chapter

1.1 Section

2.Chapter

2.1 Section

III Bibliography

IV Index

**EIDT**

I know that for the numbering of pages you can switch from `\pagenumbering{roman}` to `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. Maybe there is a similar approach to my problem.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[liststotocnumbered]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Section}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
       \centering
       \includegraphics{example.png} 
       \caption{example caption}
       \label{fig:example1}
    \end{figure}
    \index{Figure!Example1}

\subsection{Subsection}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
       \centering
       \begin{tabular}{@{} lcr @{}} 
          \toprule
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
          \cmidrule(r){1-2} 
          Animal    & Description & Price (\$)\\
          \midrule
          Gnat      & per gram & 13.65 \\
                    & each     &  0.01 \\
          Gnu       & stuffed  & 92.50 \\
          Emu       & stuffed  & 33.33 \\
          Armadillo & frozen   &  8.99 \\
          \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Tab. 1}
       \label{tab:booktabs1}
    \end{table}
    \index{Table!Example1}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Section}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
       \centering
       \includegraphics{example.png} 
       \caption{example caption}
       \label{fig:example2}
    \end{figure}
    \index{Figure!Example2}

\subsection{Subsection}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
       \centering
       \begin{tabular}{@{} lcr @{}} 
          \toprule
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
          \cmidrule(r){1-2} 
          Animal    & Description & Price (\$)\\
          \midrule
          Gnat      & per gram & 13.65 \\
                    & each     &  0.01 \\
          Gnu       & stuffed  & 92.50 \\
          Emu       & stuffed  & 33.33 \\
          Armadillo & frozen   &  8.99 \\
          \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Tab. 2}
       \label{tab:booktabs2}
    \end{table}
    \index{Table!Example2}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{BibliographyFile}

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is a little odd. It looks like the chapters are part of the List of Tables

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Sorry, my fault. All lists and chapters are of the same level. I took away the spacings. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It is not the spacing, it is the idea that the things between item B and item C belong to item B.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Please see edit. I know, this makes hardly any difference but that's how it must be. My school told me so.

Comment: @John Another case of odd requirements by people who apparently know nothing about typography (and logic, in this case). :(

Comment: @egreg I tried to convince them that their idea of typography is wrong...whatever :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the meaning of `\chapter*` that's issued for the special chapter:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newif\ifintoc
\def\@schapter#1{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \if@at@twocolumn
      \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
    \else
      \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
    \fi
  \else
    \@makeschapterhead{#1}\@afterheading
  \fi
  \ifintoc
    \stepcounter{specialchapter}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thespecialchapter}#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{specialchapter}
\renewcommand{\thespecialchapter}{\Roman{specialchapter}}

\begin{document}

\intocfalse
\tableofcontents
\intoctrue

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Section}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
       \centering
       \includegraphics{example.png} 
       \caption{example caption}
       \label{fig:example1}
    \end{figure}
    \index{Figure!Example1}

\subsection{Subsection}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
       \centering
       \begin{tabular}{@{} lcr @{}} 
          \toprule
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
          \cmidrule(r){1-2} 
          Animal    & Description & Price (\$)\\
          \midrule
          Gnat      & per gram & 13.65 \\
                    & each     &  0.01 \\
          Gnu       & stuffed  & 92.50 \\
          Emu       & stuffed  & 33.33 \\
          Armadillo & frozen   &  8.99 \\
          \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Tab. 1}
       \label{tab:booktabs1}
    \end{table}
    \index{Table!Example1}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Section}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
       \centering
       \includegraphics{example.png} 
       \caption{example caption}
       \label{fig:example2}
    \end{figure}
    \index{Figure!Example2}

\subsection{Subsection}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
       \centering
       \begin{tabular}{@{} lcr @{}} 
          \toprule
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
          \cmidrule(r){1-2} 
          Animal    & Description & Price (\$)\\
          \midrule
          Gnat      & per gram & 13.65 \\
                    & each     &  0.01 \\
          Gnu       & stuffed  & 92.50 \\
          Emu       & stuffed  & 33.33 \\
          Armadillo & frozen   &  8.99 \\
          \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{Tab. 2}
       \label{tab:booktabs2}
    \end{table}
    \index{Table!Example2}

\bibliography{BibliographyFile}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem x
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

I've added a mock bibliography just to show the result.

[image]

---

The `\listof...` commands and the `bibliography`/`index` environments issue `\chapter*` for their working and this command is defined not to add an entry in the table of contents. So I redefine it (more precisely the `\@schapter` command) to add one and in the form

```
<Roman numeral> <Title> .... <page>
```

where the numeral is obtained from a new counter that is stepped. However, since we don't want that the table of contents does the same, this part of the code is executed only if a conditional (`\ifintoc`) is true. The conditional is set to false before `\tableofcontents` and to true just after it. This last part might be made automatic, but I believe that it will be a "just once" application, so it shouldn't be a problem.

If you find that something you need to be crazy numbered isn't, just add a line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thespecialchapter}Foo}
```

in a suitable place as you did for the bibliography.

---

In order to get the number also in the headers (the usefulness of which I'm even less convinced than of putting the numbers in the table of contents), you can modify the definitions as follows (just the needed part):

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifintoc
\def\@schapter#1{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \if@at@twocolumn
      \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
    \else
      \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
    \fi
  \else
    \@makeschapterhead{#1}\@afterheading
  \fi
  \ifintoc
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \stepcounter{specialchapter}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thespecialchapter}#1}%
    \markboth{\MakeMarkcase{\thespecialchapter\ #1}}{\MakeMarkcase{\thespecialchapter\ #1}}
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcounter{specialchapter}
\renewcommand{\thespecialchapter}{\Roman{specialchapter}}
```

If you want also that the *titles* bear the number, then something like the following should do.

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifintoc
\def\@schapter#1{%
  \ifintoc
    \stepcounter{specialchapter}%
  \fi
  \if@twocolumn
    \if@at@twocolumn
      \@makeschapterhead{\ifintoc\thespecialchapter\ \fi#1}%
    \else
      \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{\ifintoc\thespecialchapter\ \fi#1}]%
    \fi
  \else
    \@makeschapterhead{\ifintoc\thespecialchapter\ \fi#1}\@afterheading
  \fi
  \ifintoc
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thespecialchapter}#1}%
    \markboth{\MakeMarkcase{\thespecialchapter\ #1}}{\MakeMarkcase{\thespecialchapter\ #1}}
  \fi}
\makeatother
\newcounter{specialchapter}
\renewcommand{\thespecialchapter}{\Roman{specialchapter}}
```

Comment: One important note: one can write `\documentclass[liststotocnumbered,bibtotocnumbered]{scrbook}` to make lists as `listoffigures`, `listoftables` and `bibliography` appear in the toc numbered. As egreg mentioned all these lists are embedded in the `\chapter*`-environment. With `liststotocnumbered,bibtotocnumbered` LaTeX seems to change the environments of these list to `\chapter`. Therefor, to make egreg's approach feasible one must delete `liststotocnumbered,bibtotocnumbered`.

Comment: In the toc everything is numbered as I wanted it to be but the headings of `\listof...` remain unnumbered. I guess one must change the `\chapter*`-environment, so that these are numbered with roman numbers. How would it be possible to implement this in your code?

Comment: @John It's possible, see edit.

Comment: I suppose that the distance between the number and the chapter's title is one space (`\thespecialchapter\ \fi#1`). Do know the exact spacing between the number and the title for the `chapter`-environment?

Comment: @John It should be `\enspace`; use `\ifintoc\thespecialchapter\autodot\enspace\fi`

Comment: The space seems to be larger than `\enspace` but it looks better now. Many thanks!