# Toc, Lof and Lot with roman number in headline

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to have such a table of contents:

**I. Table of contents**

```
II.   List of figures ..................... 3
III.  List of tables ...................... 4
1.    Section ............................. 5
1.1     Subsection ........................ 6
2.    Section ............................. 7
2.1     Subsection ........................ 8
IV.   Bibliography ........................ 9
```

All my section should have an arabic number and toc, lof, lot and bibliography should have an roman number in the headline. And I want although that the numbers in the headline appear in the table of contents.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\let \savenumberline \numberline
\def \numberline#1{\savenumberline{#1.}}¬

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
    \newpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
    \listoftables
    \newpage

    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \newpage

    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \newpage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
    \bibliography{sources}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83628/changing-enumeration-of-divisions-to-roman-numbers

Comment: The answer from the linked question doesn't work for me. It's throws no error when compiling. But it doesn't change the headlines. Maybe cause its using KOMA?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work; I was just suggesting a related question, that could help in solving your problem. Do you plan to have some usage for `\section*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch the commands producing the lists and the bibliography; I add also better ways for adding periods to the sectional numbers, both in the text and in the TOC.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\listoffigures}
  {\section*}
  {\specialsection}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}
  {\section*}
  {\specialsection}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\section*}
  {\specialsection}
  {}{}
\newcounter{specialsection}
\setcounter{specialsection}{1}
\renewcommand{\thespecialsection}{\Roman{specialsection}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\thespecialsection.\quad Table of contents}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname.\quad
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\specialsection}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{specialsection}
  \section*{\thespecialsection.\quad#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thespecialsection}#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.5em}%
  \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2.5em}%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\listoftables
\newpage

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\newpage

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{X} Y

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Note: the image has been produced using A5 paper, just for better showing the results.

[image]